# @EventHandler events not working

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to make a simple addition to my plugin so that when someone joins they receive a message that says "Heyyyyyyy". My plugin has a few commands also.

Here's my `Main` class:

```
package me.ben.test;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Click(), this);
    getLogger().info("The Plugin Has Been Enabled!");
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    getLogger().info("The Plugin Has Been Disabled!");
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label,
        String[] args) {

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hello") && sender instanceof Player) {

        Player player = (Player) sender;

        player.sendMessage("Hello, " + player.getName() + "!");

        return true;

    } else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("isonline")
            && args.length == 1) {

        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
        if (target == null) {

            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Player " + args[0]
                    + " is not online.");

            return true;

        } else if (target != null) {

            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Player " + args[0]
                    + " is online.");

            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return false;
}

}
```

and here is my `Click` class:

```
package me.ben.test;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Click extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("Heyyyyyyy");
    }
}
```

All of the `@EventHandler` things are not working so I quick made this simple one.

Comment: stackoverflow has great code formatting, please put the code with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have only one class that extends `JavaPlugin`. Remove `extends JavaPlugin` from your `Click` Class - only your main class should `extend JavaPlugin`.

Check out [Bukkit's official plugin tutorial](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial) for help on coding Bukkit Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Listener` in your `Main` class but you are not handling any event there, use it only when you want the class to be able to handler bukkit events.

You can use `Listener` with your `Main` class if you want, but you'll need to put the methods that handles events in your main class, but it'll become messy in big projects...

You also don't need to extend `JavaPlugin` everywhere, just in your main class.

If you want to use your main class:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        getLogger().info("The Plugin Has Been Enabled!");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("Heyyyyyyy");
    }
}
```

If you want to use a separated class to handle events:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Click(), this);
        getLogger().info("The Plugin Has Been Enabled!");
    }
}

public class Click implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("Heyyyyyyy");
    }
}
```

Don't forget that you need to create a `plugin.yml` file correctly otherwise nothing will work.